# How to override a site's style on the client side

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I have two pages that I visit that are very similar, but (on the client side) I would like to assign custom CSS files (or similar functionality) so they look different every time I load the page in IE. I do NOT have access to the server, I need this to be a browser-based solution. Clarifying because my first attempt at asking this was marked as a dupe: this is NOT about having a style applied only in IE, rather a client-side style overriding the site's style that needs to work on IE.

Background: We use Cisco Workload Automation (aka Tidal) to do our job scheduling through a web interface that (they claim) requires IE. My problem is that the production and non-production pages look identical except for the URL. I'd like to have them look different in my browser so that I can easily tell if I'm looking at production or non-production. (I'm separately addressing this with the admins.) I can use the developer tools to make them appear different, but the modification goes away when I leave the page. Is there a good way to do this?

Comment: From what I know this is not possible, unless you do something with IE's actual code, or some plugin or some addon or hack that can help with that. All html or web files sent through your web server host is naturally directly translated by your browser which renders that beautifully beautiful web page. Like you mentioned, it may be possible, and probably is, but it wouldn't be easy. The simplest way is to just get your web server provider or whoever's managing your websites to do it on the server backend.

Answer (score 0):

Tools > Internet Options > General Tab > Accessibility button under "Appearance" > Choose your own StyleSheet.css file

You can give some js in the link that onload adds a class to the ‘’ and use that class in the css to change something

Comment: As I understand it, that style sheet would apply to every site, I don't see a way to make it site-specific.